# Update "Player" framework for ios to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift3, xcode8

I am working on an app that uses the "Player" framework by https://github.com/piemonte Since I updated to swift 3, I get errors regarding one specific function. I am not really sure how to fix it as I am not a pro in swift 3 yet. Any help? :D

the code (swift 2.3) (please help me update it to swift 3)

```
private var PlayerObserverContext = 0
private var PlayerItemObserverContext = 0
private var PlayerLayerObserverContext = 0

    override open func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    switch (keyPath, context) {
    case (.some(PlayerRateKey), PlayerObserverContext):
        true
    case (.some(PlayerStatusKey), PlayerItemObserverContext):
        true
    case (.some(PlayerKeepUp), PlayerItemObserverContext):
        if let item = self.playerItem {
            self.bufferingState = .ready
            self.delegate?.playerBufferingStateDidChange(self)

            if item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp && self.playbackState == .playing {
                self.playFromCurrentTime()
            }
        }

        let status = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as! NSNumber).intValue as AVPlayerStatus.RawValue

        switch (status) {
        case AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay.rawValue:
            self.playerView.playerLayer.player = self.player
            self.playerView.playerLayer.isHidden = false
        case AVPlayerStatus.failed.rawValue:
            self.playbackState = PlaybackState.failed
            self.delegate?.playerPlaybackStateDidChange(self)
        default:
            true
        }
    case (.some(PlayerEmptyBufferKey), PlayerItemObserverContext):
        if let item = self.playerItem {
            if item.isPlaybackBufferEmpty {
                self.bufferingState = .delayed
                self.delegate?.playerBufferingStateDidChange(self)
            }
        }

        let status = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as! NSNumber).intValue as AVPlayerStatus.RawValue

        switch (status) {
        case AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay.rawValue:
            self.playerView.playerLayer.player = self.player
            self.playerView.playerLayer.isHidden = false
        case AVPlayerStatus.failed.rawValue:
            self.playbackState = PlaybackState.failed
            self.delegate?.playerPlaybackStateDidChange(self)
        default:
            true
        }
    case (.some(PlayerReadyForDisplay), PlayerLayerObserverContext):
        if self.playerView.playerLayer.isReadyForDisplay {
            self.delegate?.playerReady(self)
        }
    default:
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)

    }

}
```

[image: errors]

Answer (score 1):

I would unwrap `context` with a `guard` statement and match like so:

```
override open func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard let context = context else {
        return
    }

    switch (keyPath, context) {
    case (.some(PlayerRateKey), &PlayerObserverContext):
        break
    case (.some(PlayerStatusKey), &PlayerItemObserverContext):
        break
    case (.some(PlayerKeepUpKey), &PlayerItemObserverContext):
        break
    // etc
   }
}
```

That should compile and run.

I would also turn the `true`s into `break`s. I'm not sure what the `true`s were for.